# Error: Class 'App\Providers\View' not found

Tags: laravel

I have cloned a laravel project from my friend through GitHub. I've updated (basically installed) composer to the project. After some installation steps, I got the following error.

```
Error

  Class 'App\Providers\View' not found

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider.php:27
    23|      * @return void
    24|      */
    25|     public function boot()
    26|     {
  > 27|         View::composer(
    28|             'layouts.products', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\viewComposer'
    29|         );
    30|
    31|             View::composer('layouts.products', function ($view) {

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:37
      App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::boot()

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:37
      call_user_func_array([])
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

The project is working fine for my friend, what's the lacking part in the cloned project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an include in your class. In your `ComposerServiceProvider.php` put the following.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But my friend doesn't have that include in his class. Why should I include it? Asking to seek knowledge about what I am doing.

Comment: @shaneeqa they could potentially have `use View;` but either way that class needs to be imported/aliased as it doesn't exist in the `App\Providers` namespace